# Array.prototype.sort(), не могу разобраться, как это работает

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
 var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
    numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    console.log(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

1.Возьмем вот этот пример из доки. Что тут a, а что b? Это элементы массива numbers? Если да, каким образом выбранные?

2.Если без параметров, `.sort(function(){ return Math.random()-0.5; })` - работающий код для случайной тасовки массива. 
Math.random()-0.5 - рандомное число (-0,5; 0,5]. 
Какой логический смысл в сортировке по 0, по 0,1 и тд (понятна сортировка по id например, по возрасту, по числу не понятна)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `a` и `b` это элементы массива `numbers`. Выбраны они могут быть как угодно. Поскольку любой алгоритм сортировки содержит в себе сравнение двух элементов, вам нужно лишь задать правило сравнения произвольных двух элементов массива. И не важно какие у них индексы.
2. По вашей же ссылке сказано:

> Если compareFunction(a, b) меньше 0, сортировка поставит a по меньшему индексу, чем b, то есть, a идёт первым.
>
> Если compareFunction(a, b) вернёт 0, сортировка оставит a и b неизменными по отношению друг к другу, но отсортирует их по отношению ко всем другим элементам.
>
> Если compareFunction(a, b) больше 0, сортировка поставит b по меньшему индексу, чем a.

То есть в случае с `Math.random() - 0.5` у вас будет получено какое-то значение. И если это значение будет 0.1 или 0.7 значения уже не имеет, так как и в том, и в другом случае оно больше 0.

Но, опять же, по вашей ссылке сказано ещё следующее:

> Функция compareFunction(a, b) должна всегда возвращать одинаковое значение для определённой пары элементов a и b. Если будут возвращаться непоследовательные результаты, порядок сортировки будет не определён.

В случае, если цель - отсортировать элементы в случайном порядке, ничего плохого не будет, но если нужен какой-то хитрый алгоритм, то этой следует всё же учитывать.

Answer (score 2):

В функцию-параметр передаются 2 параметра: `a` и `b`. `a` - i-тый элемент массива, `b` - i-тый + 1.

То есть это как если бы вы прошлись по массиву циклом `for` и тело этого цикла выглядело бы так:

```
// for (...) {
    var a = numbers[i];
    var b = numbers[i + 1];
// }
```

А дальше цитата:

> Если compareFunction(a, b) меньше 0, сортировка поставит a по меньшему индексу, чем b, то есть, a идёт первым.
>
> Если compareFunction(a, b) вернёт 0, сортировка оставит a и b неизменными по отношению друг к другу, но отсортирует их по отношению ко всем другим элементам. Обратите внимание: стандарт ECMAscript не гарантирует данное поведение, и ему следуют не все браузеры (например, версии Mozilla по крайней мере, до 2003 года).
>
> Если compareFunction(a, b) больше 0, сортировка поставит b по меньшему индексу, чем a.

Если я правильно понял ваш (второй) вопрос, то вам непонятно, почему используются какие-то нули, единицы, больше и меньше для сортировки.

Собственно ответ находится в цитате выше. Например, если функция сортировки будет выглядеть как

```
function(a, b) {
    return -123;
}
```

То возвращать она будет постоянно -123 (не очень практично и функционально, сугубо для примера), что меньше ноля, следовательно "сортировка поставит a по меньшему индексу, чем b, то есть, a идёт первым".

*Какой логический смысл в сортировке по 0, по 0,1 и тд (понятна сортировка по id например, по возрасту, по числу не понятна)?*

Смысл заключается в том, что `#random()-0.5` будет постоянно давать случайные значения, причем значения будут либо отрицательные, либо положительные, либо равные нолю. И Именно эти 3 случая как раз и необходимы для перетасовки массива. Выпадет число меньше ноля - a станет раньше b, выпадет больше - поменяются местами, выпадет равное нолю - все останется как было (за исключением случаев, описанных в цитате выше).